# Imperative parallels to Haskell's Monad operations

Tags: haskell, monad, imperative-programming

Would it be (mostly) correct to say that the following are the parallels to the Haskell `Monad` operations in the imperative world?

- `Monad`'s `>>` ~ C/C++/JavaScript/etc. `,` operator
- `do` expressions ~ C/C++/JavaScript/etc. `;` operator (kinda)
- `MonadFail`'s `fail` ~ C/C++/JavaScript/etc. `throw`

---

To demonstrate the point, some examples:

### Sequentially evaluate, but discard first result:

Haskell:

```hs
a = doSomething >> doSomethingElse
```

C++:

```cpp
auto a = (doSomething(), doSomethingElse());
```

JavaScript:

```js
const a = (doSomething(), doSomethingElse());
```

### Evaluate one after the other, reusing previous results:

Haskell:

```hs
do a <- doSomething
   doSomethingWith a
```

JavaScript:

```js
const a = doSomething();
doSomethingWith(a);
```

Comment: For C++ the equivalent is `std::optional`, can't tell for Java or C.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're thinking about `Maybe`, but it's not the only `Monad`... I was thinking more about `Monad` in general

Comment: `std::optional`s can be easily chained.

Comment: I know, this isn't about `std::optional` though, it's about [Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad)

Comment: Haskell doesn't really have `doSomething`. It's all `someValue`, so `>>` is only relevant in composing effects. `do` notation generalises language and library features like `foreach`, `async`, `if error goto fail`, logging etc.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, let's assume `doSomething` is effectful (hence the name).

Comment: its almost not worth considering >> at all as it just follows from >>=. The type constructor, >>= and return define a type that is a monad (assuming they meet the laws)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it helps you wrap your head around it, your intuition is a decent analogy for *some monads*. Consider, however, the list monad:

```hs
Prelude> [1, 2, 3] >> [4, 5, 6]
[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6]
Prelude> [1, 2, 3] >>= \x -> map (*x) [4, 5, 6]
[4,5,6,8,10,12,12,15,18]
-- Doesn't even have a fail
```

Monads are a much more abstract concept than most imperative programmers are accustomed to dealing with. It's okay to start on the path to understanding them by focusing on a few specific monads, but long term don't make your understanding of them too narrow.